# ImportError: cannot import name 'commands' from 'discord.ext' (unknown location) ```

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I got an ImportError. Can someone help me?

```py
from discord.ext import commands
```

Error:

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands' from 'discord.ext' (unknown location)
```

My imports are

````py
import discord
import datetime
import asyncio
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions
from discord_components import Button, Select, SelectOption, ComponentsBot, interaction
from discord_components.component import ButtonStyle
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_option ```
````

Comment: 1. how are you running this? IDE/CLI?

Comment: 2. how are you managing your dependencies and environment?

Comment: @ClauSt I'm running this by VScode

Answer (score 0):

Trying to go at this as "let's try and learn from this" approach.

1. As always, what have you tried to address this?
2. VSCode is not a full IDE (like pycharm), so you have to configure most things for your desired language. It's lite, but I suggest using pycharm as it's easier and it's 100% focused on python with better handling than VSCode. And it can manage your project specific environment with ease.
3. Pretty sure that you don't have any dependencies installed and that's why it's failing. So first check [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)(comes out of the box) or [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) for managing dependencies and your python environment.
4. The IDE sometimes gets in the way of better understanding the underlying flow, so I suggest just using the python REPL or ipython if you want to be fancy (still needs to be installed as a dependency).

Just taking venv and using CLI as an example (and a linux/macOS terminal), the simplest to start here is :

```
# setup your python project-specific environment
python -m venv .venv

source .venv/bin/activate

# noww we can start install dependencies with pip
pip install discord

# now we can run that little snippet, considering that you have your dependencies installed
python my_discord_script.py
```